# Erratic scrollbar in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, tabulator

When I scroll down a long table really fast in Internet Explorer 11 the scrollbar starts to jump around (mostly up), Firefox and Chrome work fine.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Here is a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdKlD.gif) of what happens and here a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60wdkyh7/) demo.

```
var tabledata = [];
for(let i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    tabledata.push({"id":i,"column1":i,"column2":i,"column3":i,"column4":i,"column5":i,"column6":i});
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:500,
    data:tabledata,
    columns:[
        {title: "id", field:"id"},
        {title:"column1", field:"column1"},
        {title:"column2", field:"column2"},
        {title:"column3", field:"column3"},
        {title:"column4", field:"column4"},
        {title:"column5", field:"column5"},
        {title:"column6", field:"column6"}
    ]
});

table.redraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the virtual DOM struggling to keep up because IE has a very inefficient JavaScript engine.

While Tabulator works on Internet Explorer the experience is degraded as it lacks a lot of the JavaScript functionality of later browsers

Comment: I just want to make sure I made my point clear. It's not about the table flickering, I absolutely understand that IE has a hard time rendering the DOM elements. My concern is the scrollbar jumping up making it impossible to scroll down the whole table. Doesn't this indicate some kind of height calculation error at some point?

Comment: Ahh with you now. yes that is a known issue when the row height is reasonably large, it is down to be fixed in the next minor release

Comment: And just one further question: In an attempt to reduce the flickering I tried setting `virtualDomBuffer:1000`. I expected this would increase the number of rendered rows on the page, but `$(".tabulator-row").length` always returns `38` regardless of the `virtualDomBuffer` setting. So obviously this isn't how this buffer works, but how does it work? :) Thanks!